# How to get more information on exception error?

Tags: python

How can I get more information on the type of exception error ?
For example, in the code below I know the exception is gonna be *ZeroDivisionError*.

```
try:
    print(1/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Error")
```

But I want to be able to get the information on the type of error without having to define it. I saw this example somewhere but it generates syntax error for me.

```
try:
   return int(var)
except ValueError, Argument:
   print "The argument does not contain numbers\n", Argument
```

What I am mainly looking for is something like

```
try:
   // Do something
except:
   // Print out an information on the type of error
```

Comment: Try to print the error object itself. Every exception implements the `__str__()` method, so print the exception object and it will automatically call the `__str__()`. Try this, `except ZeroDivisionError as e:print(e)`.

Comment: You have not marked any answer as selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    # Do something
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

You can replace `Exception` with `ZeroDivisionError` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stacktrace to get all the info about error.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

```
import stacktrace
try:
   // Do something
except:
   print(traceback.format_exc())
```